# Replace Routed Component with Mock based on environment

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Component (e.g. **DataComponent** for displaying some list in a table). Now I want to test the View of the Component manually (starting app in browser and clicking around, see behaviour, etc.).
For this purpose however I dont want to display the real data (loaded from some backend) but I want to display some testdata.

I have created another Component **MockDataComponent** extends **DataComponent**, which loads my testdata. Additionally I have created another environment *test.environment.ts* and added a flag **test** to the environment, to indicate if I want to load the real data, or the testdata.

So far so good. But how do I tell Angular, which Component to load?

Since **DataComponent** is routed, the first thing that came to my mind is to define my routes as follows:

```
{path: 'data', component: environment.test ? MockDataComponent : DataComponent}
```

However as far as I know, this would mean, that both Components are compiled, no matter in which environment I am starting my app. Additionally this mixes up my test-code with the code for the actual app, which i want to avoid.

My question is: Is there a way, to tell Angular to replace all instances of **DataComponent** with instances of **MockDataComponent** (based on environment), while keeping the test-code seperated from the "real" code?

Im looking for something like the providers array inside an @NgModule annotation, just for components. Something like:

```
{provide: DataComponent, useClass: MockDataComponent}
```